# Set/Reset Statusbar on a Different Workspace

Tags: python, workspaces

I can write some text on the statusbar on the active workspace.

```
bpy.context.workspace.status_text_set("Hello World")
```

[image: Setting statusbar text]

Then I can reset to normal with

```
bpy.context.workspace.status_text_set(None)
```

[image: Reset statusbar text]

I would like to set and reset statusbar text on a different workspace.
I would think that getting the different workspaces and calling the status_text_set method on them would work, but did not. E.g. with

```
bpy.data.workspaces[0]
bpy.data.workspaces[0].status_text_set("Hello World")
```

I reach the Animation workspace. But calling status_text_set on that workspace will not write on that statusbar, but on the active statusbar, presently the 'Scripting'.

[image: Trying to set Animation workspace statusbar]

Definitelly something wrong with my logic, but can someone enlighten me, how I could write and reset other workspaces?

(I would like to write some non-context related status message with a background process. If the user switches from workspace to workspace meanwhile, the text will appear there as well, but finally, when the process is over, I want to reset the statusbars, and it will do it only on the last active workspace statusbar.)

Thank you for your help.
Happy Blending!
z

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `draw()` method of class `STATUSBAR_HT_header`

```
import bpy

def register():

    # testprop: change animation workspace from scripting statusbar
    bpy.types.Scene.status_test = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False , name="Change Animation Workspace")

    statusbar_draw = bpy.types.STATUSBAR_HT_header.draw   # original

    def draw_statusbar(self, context):                    # new layout
        layout = self.layout

        if context.workspace.name == 'Scripting':                               # original elements
            layout.label(text = "Status:")            
            layout.template_input_status()                                      # Status       
            layout.separator_spacer()          
            layout.prop(context.scene, 'status_test')
            layout.label(text = "Reports:")
            layout.template_reports_banner()                                    # Messages
            layout.template_running_jobs()                                      # Progress Bar
            layout.separator_spacer()          
            layout.label(text = "Stats:")
            row = layout.row()                
            row.alignment = 'RIGHT'            
            row.label(text=context.screen.statusbar_info(), translate=False)    # Stats & Info             
            layout.label(text = "* nothing more here *")            

        elif context.scene.status_test and context.workspace.name == 'Animation':
            layout.label(text = "Wow! ... I´m in the statusbar")

        else:
            statusbar_draw(self, context)  # original status bar

    bpy.types.STATUSBAR_HT_header.draw = draw_statusbar   # replace 
                    
def unregister():
    bpy.types.STATUSBAR_HT_header.draw = statusbar_draw   # reset

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `msgbus` and subscribe to the `workspace` property of the window class: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html#bpy.types.Window.workspace

[image]

```
import bpy

handle = object()

# Triggers when widow's scene is changed
subscribe_to = bpy.types.Window, "workspace"

def notify_test(context):
    print(context.workspace.name)
    context.workspace.status_text_set("Hello: {}".format(context.workspace.name))

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=subscribe_to,
    owner=handle,
    args=(bpy.context,),
    notify=notify_test,
)

bpy.msgbus.publish_rna(key=subscribe_to)
```

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.msgbus.html

[How to get an event when an object is selected?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/150809/how-to-get-an-event-when-an-object-is-selected)

[Msgbus - How to subscribe to bpy.context.scene?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204906/msgbus-how-to-subscribe-to-bpy-context-scene)